# How do I get actions posted via the graph to show up in hte users feed and not the activity log?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Currently when my app posts on a users behalf the custom action shows up in the activity log and not on the user's wall. I am expecting the action to show up in /me/feed in the open graph. I am using the c# library. Below is the code I am using:

```
    public async Task JoinSmaxNation(int nationId)
    {
        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters.smax_nation = String.Format(_smaxNationUrlFormat, nationId, UserId);
        parameters.no_feed_story = false;
        parameters.expires_in = 86400;

        dynamic result = await _fb.PostTaskAsync("me/smaxsport:join", parameters);
    }
```

Comment: It looks like the fb:explicitly_shared=true option was required.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the fb:explicitly_shared=true option was required.